# How do I loop through an array of my answers and hints in my JavaScript word game?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops

I am working on a word game project. My problem is that I have the game post the word and not the hints (I have them linked to a button) and when I press the button it executes all of the hints and I only want one hint per word. Each word has a hint that is in the same order as each other (i.e hint 0 matches word 0 in the array). There is no CSS because I am focusing on the functionality over styling at the moment. 
I am also really bad at explaining things and I am open to clarifying anything I might have failed to mention.
The code is listed below.

**`HTML`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/main.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Degrassi Next Class</h1>
    <h2>Word Game</h2>
    <h3> Click on with your mouse or enter a letter with your keyboard to start</h3>
</div>

<div id="simpson"></div>
<br>
<br>
<button id="spoiler">#spoileralert</button>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**JS**

```
var degrassi = [
    "Maya", "Zig", "Lola", "Frankie", "Yael", "Tiny", "Zoe", "Tristan", "Grace", "Esme", "Winston", "Hunter", "Vijay", "Rasha", "Goldi", "Jonah", "Baaz", "Miles", "Saad", "Shay"
];


// select a random character
var currentCharacter = degrassi[Math.floor(Math.random() * degrassi.length)];

// the array that loops through characters
var charactersArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < currentCharacter.length; i++) {
    charactersArray[i] = "_";
}

var lettersLeft = currentCharacter.length;


var simpson = document.getElementById("simpson");
simpson.innerHTML = charactersArray.join(" ");


// hints also knows as spoiler alert
var spoilerz = document.getElementById.spoiler.onclick = function () {
    var spoiler = [
        "Their sister visits from college due to a tragedy",
        "Only character to be in a polyamourus relationship",
        "This character had an abortion",
        "This character has a twin",
        "This character is generqueer",
        "This character was in a gang with his brother",
        "This character was on an actor on West Drive",
        "This character was in a coma after a bus crash",
        "This characters nickname is The Watcher",
        "This character pushed their significant other down a hill",
        "This characters nickname is Chewy",
        "This character caused a school lockdown",
        'First line: "Oh My God! I love high school."',
        "This character was prom queen with their significant other",
        "This character is president of the feminist club",
        "This character has a daughter",
        "This character has an older sister who graduated in 2016",
        "This characters father is abusive",
        "This characters nickname is Creepy Camera Guy",
        "This character was in a love triangle with her best friend"
    ];

    // selects a spoiler this should coorespond with the character
    var currentSpoiler = spoiler[Math.floor(Math.random() * spoiler.length)];


    // loop through spoilers
    var spoilerArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < currentSpoiler.length; i++) {
        spoilerArray[i] = "_";
    }

};
```

Comment: U left out the problem/question with your current code?

Comment: You have an array, and you are looping through it already, so where the issue/error?

Comment: I thought I said my error but I guess I didn't.

Comment: My issue was there are two separate loops and I wanted them to loop together to correspond both the name and the hint. Sorry if I am not clear, programming is not my first language.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are choosing two times a random number. This is probably not what you want, because that will return (in most cases) two different numbers like e.g 2 and 4.
You should define a new number (let's say `var index`) and assume it a random number. As both arrays (`spoiler` and `degrassi`) have the same length, you could take the length of `degrassi`.

To get your code working, you should replace
`var currentCharacter = degrassi[Math.floor(Math.random() * degrassi.length)];` with
`var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * degrassi.length);
var currentCharacter = degrassi[index]` and
`var currentSpoiler = spoiler[Math.floor(Math.random() * spoiler.length)];`
 with  `var currentSpoiler = spoiler[index];`

You also need something to output your spoiler, but as I don't see where you want to do that, I can't help you at this point

Comment: This is really helpful.
I didn't think to make a div tag in my HTML to output the spoiler but I am going to do that.

Answer (score 0):

As Nicola answer above, you need to assign your random number to a variable instead of calling it twice.

I can also suggest that you construct your array as one array of objects like this:

```
 var degrassi = [
    {name: "Maya", hint:"Their sister visits from college due to a tragedy"}, //remaining names and hints ]; 

  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * degrassi.length)
```

then you can call your character name and hint like this:

```
degrassi[random].name  //gives you the name
degrassi[random].hint  //gives you its corresponding hint
```

This will make your code easier to change and maintain as well as add more names and hints etc..